# When work done by external force is negative in electrostatic

Tags: electrostatics

Why my external work equals the negative of the work done by electric force if i move positive test charge from infinity to a certain point in the electric field of positive charge

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No i studied the lesson And have some questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bringing a test change from infinity to a specified location involves no change in kinetic energy. There must be no net force on the test charge at all times and the test charge is moved with a constant speed to the target location. Therefore, an equal and oppposite external force is needed to balance the electric force. The work done by the two forces therefore have opposite signs.

The potential is simply this external force integrated from infinity to the target location.

Comment: And when it arrives at the point we need will it repel And go away to infinity

Comment: @Ahmad Eldesokey: If we stop exerting this force, it will of course go back to infinity and we get back the same amount of work.

Comment: Why should we move the test charge slowly

Comment: @user7777777 All that is required is that the charge starts and finishes with the same speed (kinetic energy). It could move at a large but constant speed to achieve this.

Comment: How the test charge will start to move from infinity if the net force on it is zero

Comment: @Ahmad Eldesokey: It has an infinitesimal velocity such that the energy used to gain this kinetic energy is negligible. Or it could already have kinetic energy. All we require is that the speed doesn't change. That's it.

Comment: I think it is not necessary that the speed stay constant we could accelerate at the begainning And then deccelerate to end with the same speed